# Can't use `find_by` method while `where` works in ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a method like this, that works fine.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.find_or_create_from_twitter_id(twitter_id)
        user = where(twitter_id: twitter_id).first
        user ||= create_from_twitter_id(twitter_id)
    end
end
```

Then I changed `where(...).first` to `find_by`, because I thought the two expression are basically same.

```
def self.find_or_create_from_twitter_id(twitter_id)
    user = find_by(twitter_id: twitter_id)
    user ||= create_from_twitter_id(twitter_id)
end
```

But I get `` undefined method `find_by' for #<Class:0x007fbb2b674970> `` error when I try to create a `User`.

I have no idea why `find_by` doesn't work here. I'll be very grateful if you tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) method is introduced in Rails 4. If you're using Rails 3.x or lesser version then use: `find_by_<attribute_name>` instead:

```
find_by_twitter_id(twitter_id)
```

But, then there's another method which find and create by the attributes passed to it, which you can use if it fits your needs:

```
find_or_create_by_twitter_id(twitter_id)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write rails version. I'm using `rails (4.1.7)`. Is there any other cause of this you can imagine?

Comment: Oh, interesting! Can you do me a favor? Try: `User.find_by(name: 'some name')` in your rails console and let me know if it works?

Comment: Yes, it works fine like `User.find_by(id: 1)`.  And in rails console `User.find_or_create_from_twitter_id("1")` works also fine. It doesn't works only when it is called from OAuth callback.

Comment: Ok try with `self.find_by(...` but I am not sure if it's relevant.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't works neither, but at least I know this is a strange behavior. Thanks!

Comment: oh, how dumb I am! I didn't restart rails server after upgrade rails version. I'm terrible sorry and thank you help me.